# How to get spring bean from context in freemarker macros?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, macros, freemarker

I need to get spring bean from `WebApplicationContext` in macros.
My attempt is to do the following:

```
<#macro categoryName category>
    <#assign context=springMacroRequestContext.webApplicationContext>
    <#assign lb=context.getBean("localizationBean")/>
    <#assign pp=context.getBean("phraseProvider")/>
    <#assign categoryName=pp.getPhrase(lb.getCategoryMnemo(category))/>
    ${categoryName}
</#macro>
```

But this is failing. First of all if I provide a bean name which is a string to `getBean` it returns an Object which I have to cast somehow, I've also tried to provide fully qualified class name but freemarker didn't like it. So how to do it ?

Comment: FreeMarker is a dynamically typed language, so casting isn't needed (nor does exist) in it. Why do you think you need to cast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to pass a bean from controller and use it in a macros then.

Also I would suggest if you have for example `User` entity in your domain to create a related macros file like `user-macroses.ftl` where all user related macroses are placed.

And if in some of the macroses you need to call some spring bean method you should create a bean like `UserFtlMacroses` where you put user related logic, so when on the view you call some macros `<@user.doSomething/>` the macros `doSomething` will call a method from `UserFtlMacroses`.